# How to change the ToggleSwitch language

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have the option in the app to change the language, however the language of the ToggleSwitch doesn't appear to change after setting:

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de" //or "en"
```

The language only changes after restarting the app yet I want it to change immediately. Even if I create a new ToggleSwitch the language will still be the previous one.

Comment: You'll have to show us your `ToggleSwitch` definition. Are you using the MultilingualAppToolkit? Have you made sure to translate the resources you are using?

Comment: I have the default ToggleSwitch, I'm not using the MultilingualAppToolkit. I do translate the other parts in the app well, I'm stuck on the last part, the ToggleSwitches (which should be automatically).